# Does 2d Array Work in glUniformMatrix4fv, C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have a 4x4 matrix class that holds the values as 2d float array : float mat[4][4]; and I overloaded the [] operator

`inline float *Matrix4::operator[](int row)
{
    return mat[row];
}`

and I have an uniform mat4 in my shader (uniform mat4 Bones[64];) which i will upload my data onto. And I hold the bones as a Matrix4 pointer (Matrix4 *finalBones) which is a matrix array, containing numJoints elements. and this is what i use to upload the data :

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.getLocation("Bones"),numJoints,false,finalBones[0][0]);
```

I am totally unsure about what is going to happen, so i need to ask that if this will work or i need to extract everything into 16*numJoints sized float arrays which seems to be expensive for each tick.

edit
this is what i have done which seems really expensive for each draw operation

```
void MD5Loader::uploadToGPU()
{
float* finalmat=new float[16*numJoints];
for (int i=0; i < numJoints; i++)
    for (int j=0; j < 4; j++)
        for(int k=0; k < 4; k++)
            finalmat[16*i + j*4 + k] = finalBones[i][j][k];


glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.getLocation("Bones"),numJoints,false,finalmat);

delete[] finalmat;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends on two things. Assuming your compiler is C++03, (and you care about standards compliance), then your `Matrix` class *must* be [a POD type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178176/734069). It must, in particular, have no constructors. C++11 [relaxes these rules significantly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/734069).

The other thing is that your matrix appears to be row-major. I say this because your `operator[]` seems to think that your 2D array is row-major. The first coordinate is the `row` rather than the column, so it's row-major storage order.

If you're going to give OpenGL row-major matrices, you need to *tell* it that they are row-major:

> glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.getLocation("Bones"), numJoints, GL_TRUE, finalBones[0][0]);

Comment: @deniz: First of all, that's a new question. If you have a new question, you should ask a new question. Second of all, you should be using a `std::vector<GLfloat>`, not an array. Third and most importantly... *why did you do that*? I *just told you* how to give OpenGL matrices that are row major. Lastly, stop passing the C++ `true` and `false` for `GLboolean` values `GL_TRUE` and `GL_FALSE`.

Comment: umm, my matrix4 class has constructors but it has only mat[4][4] as a variable. everything else is operator overloading and basic matrix functions. i am not sure if it is POD in c++03

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, a class with [standard layout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) can be cast to a pointer, addressing its first member, and back again. With a **sizeof** check, you then have a guarantee of contiguous matrix data:

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert((sizeof(Matrix4) == (sizeof(GLfloat) * 16)) &&
              (std::is_standard_layout<Matrix4>::value),
              "Matrix4 does not satisfy contiguous storage requirements");
```

[Trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) (or POD) layouts are just too restrictive once you have non-trivial constructors, etc. Your post suggests you will need to set the `transpose` parameter to `GL_TRUE`.